# Methods' name type and generate C#

Tags: c#, methods

```
    //snake-eyes test 

using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;
public class C_ADice
{
    private int m_output = 0;
    public void Roll(int value)
    {
        m_output = value;
    }
    public int Result()
    {
        return m_output;
    }
}
interface ICounter
{
    int Counter();
    int Times();
    int Total();
}
public class counterbycase : ICounter
{
    int m_counter = 0, m_times = 0;
    int m_total = 0;
    public counterbycase (int a, int b ,int c)
    {
        m_counter = c;
        m_times = a;
        m_total = b;        
    }
    int ICounter.Counter()
    {
        return m_counter;
    }
    int ICounter.Times()
    {
        return m_times;
    }
    int ICounter.Total()
    {
        return m_total;
    }
}




public class Snake_eyes_start
{
    //public delegate void SnakeEyeDefected(int d1, int d2);
    public string casename(int a)
    {
        return "c" + a.ToString();
    }
    public static void Main()

    {
        int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
        Random diceroller = new Random();

        C_ADice Dice_1 = new C_ADice();
        C_ADice Dice_2 = new C_ADice();

        ICounter[] casenumber = new ICounter[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {   
            int times = 0;


            do
            {   times ++;
                Dice_1.Roll(diceroller.Next(1, 7));
                Dice_2.Roll(diceroller.Next(1, 7));
                Console.WriteLine("Results are {0} and {1} ", Dice_1.Result(), Dice_2.Result());

            } while (Dice_1.Result() * Dice_2.Result() != 1);
            Console.WriteLine("Snake eyes defected");
            counterbycase casename(times) = new counterbycase(); 
        }



    }
}
```

counterbycase xxxxxx = new counterbycase();

I don't know if I can automatically generate names to replace the "xxxxxx", 
I wonder if that xxxxxx is string?

Sincerely, 
Thanks,
Cheers, (Sorry, I have to add some more text to balance the code)

Hung NGuyen

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Also, your code won't compile ... you cannot instantiate an instance of an interface like that. Please rephrase your question so it is clearer.

Comment: "what type is the method's name" - *what*?

Comment: If the goal is to generate the members in the code (e.g. *when* writing code), ReSharper can do this with the ["Implement Members"](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Implementing_Overriding_Methods.html) action - I have no idea if there is any native VS action. (ReSharper does this by analyzing the types in question and locating suitable members to implement/stub.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is add the `new counterbycase()` to the array that you've established for it:

```
casenumber[i] = new counterbycase(times, total, counter);
```